# Left join returns null, even though there is a matching value

Tags: sql, mariadb

2 tables. I match on column `ProductIdentifier` which is present in both tables. The left table is a big table with many records and ProductIdentifier is not unique and the same value will be present multiple times. The right table has only limited records and a maximum of 1 matching value (this column is unique).

I execute the following query.

```
select  distinct `upe`.`ProductIdentifier` AS `ProductIdentifier`,
        `pmt`.`ProductIdentifier` AS `PMT_ID`
    from       `prices`.`unassigned_price_entries` `upe`
    left join  `prices`.`product_match_table` `pmt`
       on (`pmt`.`ProductIdentifier` = `upe`.`ProductIdentifier`)
    where  `upe`.`ProductIdentifier` like '%Brand%'
```

Basically, all works well, except for one thing. The result is like this:

```
ProductIdentifier | PMT_ID
----------------------------
Brand A           | Brand A
Brand A           | Brand A
Brand B           | Brand B
Brand B           | NULL
```

I don't understand. It can match Brand B obviously but doesn't do it the second time. It does however for A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would occur if the two values for `upe.ProductIdentifier` did not have the same value.  They might look the same but be different, for various reasons:

- Leading or trailing spaces.
- Hidden characters in the string.
- Look-alike characters in some collations.

If you use `where upe.ProductIdentifier = 'Brand B'`, you will probably get only one of the rows (there is a possibility that neither would match).

Comment: I tried what you said and indeed I only retrieved the one that matched on Brand B. The row with NULL didn't appear. The thing is, I already checked for spaces or if they wouldn't be identical. Guess I'll have to go check for hidden characters. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Check it with `HEX(ProductIdentifier)`